How to fix corrupt raspberry pi backup image
I made a backup of a bootable raspberry pi usb flash drive using disk utility on a mac. Apparently the disk image is corrupt and I no longer have the original USB flash drive. I have tried to see if I can fix the issue using TestDisk on my mac to no avail. I still have the contents of the flash drive (files) and also wanted to see if i could recreate the boot drive from these files
I am hoping someone can help me figure out if I can fix it and how. I appreciate any help I can get. Thanks!
Here are the testdisk errors found:




Here is a thread about solving this error. https://www.partitionwizard.com/news/bad-gpt-partition-invalid-signature.html

The Mac and Disk Utility is completely unable to make a backup of a bootable RPi USB drive... it's a different filesystem. If you had used dd instead of Disk Utility, you might have had a different outcome; dd is not ideal for backups, but chances are reasonably good that if you'd done it correctly you would have something you could use.
So - that's past, and all you can do now is chalk this up to experience. In the future, if you want a good backup system for your RPi (as long as it's running some flavor of the RPi OS), you should use image-backup - a part of the image-utils "bundle". There are several answers here that describe features, how it works, and where to download it - this one for example.

If you used a Mac (or Windows) tool you DON'T have a backup because neither understands Linux file systems and can't backup MBR disks.
At best you might be able to mount on a Linux computer and recover some of your data.
ONE backup is a false sense of security and an untested backup is worse.

Thank you Confucius.
